# Measure a distance between the start and end of a drag

Tags: unity, vector, mouse, linear-algebra

I tried to measure a distance from one point to another point on my phone screen by using following code:

```
Vector3 startPoint;
Vector3 endPoint;
public Camera cam;
float distanceX;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 startPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        Vector3 endPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        distanceX = Mathf.Abs(startPoint.x - endPoint.x);
        Debug.Log(distanceX);
    }
}
```

But this code does not give me the correct result and I don't know why...

> Editor's note: this is where you should write what result the code *does* return and how that result differs from the result you *expect* for a specific test case, or several.

Answer (score 2):

There are some obvious mistakes here. Firstly:

```
Vector3 startPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
```

This does not store your start position in your member variable `startPoint` so you can read it back on a later frame. This creates a *new* temporary variable called `startPoint` that you throw away at the end of the function - we say that this temporary variable "[shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)" the member variable, so any references their shared name will refer to the temporary instead of the member variable as you intended. Remove the `Vector3` in front to use the member variable instead.

Secondly, you don't provide a depth value to `ScreenToWorldPoint`. This can still work if your camera is orthographic, but if you're using a perspective camera then you're asking "What's the position on this ray at a distance of 0 units from the camera?" - no matter what screen position you use for that ray, the answer is always the camera's own position.

You may want to assign `Input.mousePosition` to a `Vector3` variable, and set its z coordinate to your chosen depth. Or fire a ray using `ScreenPointToRay` and check where that ray intersects your scene, using the hit position as your `start`/`endPoint`.

Thirdly, this only measures distances along the world x axis. You can use `Vector3.Distance()` if you want to measure the distance on all axes. Or, if you want to measure a pixel distance on your screen, you can skip the `ScreenToWorldPoint` conversion entirely, and work with your `Input.mousePosition` `Vector2`s directly.